# create files in while loop with dynamic conent

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have one csv file that has

```
user1,abcd
user2,efgh
user2,ijkl
```

I want to create files by looping while like

```
/home/user1/t.txt ---> file content---> user1,abcd
/home/user2/t.txt ---> file content ---> user2,efgh
/home/user3/t.txt ---> file content ---> user3,ijkl
...
```

like this

```
while IFS="," read -r reccol1 reccol2
  do
   echo "creating file at /home/$reccol1/t.txt"
   cat >/home/$reccol1/t.txt << EOF
   $reccol1,$rec_col2
   EOF
done < <(tail -n +1 list_users.csv)
```

Comment: So create them.... ? What is the problem? `   EOF` the line with `EOF` has to be exactly only `EOF`. No spaces in front.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.